# File uploads in Version 3 of the Google Drive SDK

Tags: go, google-drive-api

I have some code that is based on the following Golang example at https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert.

```
// InsertFile creates a new file in Drive from the given file and details
func InsertFile(d *drive.Service, title string, description string,
parentId string, mimeType string, filename string) (*drive.File, error) {
             .
             .
             . 
  f := &drive.File{Title: title, Description: description, MimeType: mimeType}
  if parentId != "" {
    p := &drive.ParentReference{Id: parentId}
    f.Parents = []*drive.ParentReference{p}
  }
  r, err := d.Files.Insert(f).Media(m).Do()
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("An error occurred: %v\n", err)
    return nil, err
  }
  return r, nil
}
```

When I switch to version 3, the errors below are thrown.

```
./main.go:125: unknown drive.File field 'Title' in struct literal
./main.go:127: undefined: drive.ParentReference
./main.go:128: undefined: drive.ParentReference
./main.go:131: service.Files.Insert undefined (type *drive.FilesService has no field or method Insert)
```

I know that Title should be changed to Name in the first error but I'm not sure what replaced drive.ParentReference or service.Files.Insert in Version 3 of the SDK and I haven't been able to find anything equivalent to the link above in the V3 docs.

Comment: I'm not sure about the parent reference, but for Drive v3, the method is called 'create' instead of insert: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth perusing the Google API go source code [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/blob/master/drive/). You can see how `ParentReference` [exists in the v2 API code](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/blob/master/drive/v2/drive-gen.go#L1714) but [does not exist in v3](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/blob/master/drive/v3/drive-gen.go). The API appears to have changed significantly from v2 to v3.

Extrapolating from these changes, here's a sketch of what the v3 equivalent for uploading a file might look like:

```
import "google.golang.org/api/drive/v3"
func InsertFile(d *drive.Service, title string, description string, mimeType string, filename string) (*drive.File, error) {
    f := &drive.File{Name: filename, Description: description, MimeType: mimeType}
    return d.Files.Create(f).do()
}
```

Comment: You are right.  I should go to the source more and I do with community driven open source code but, for projects backed by a commercial entity like Google, I expect top notch, up-to-date documentation.

Your suggestion worked almost verbatim.  The d in do() should be capitalized.  Thank you Jeff.